# Smoother boundaries between components of segmented image

Tags: image-processing, finite-element-method, mesh, smoothing

I'd like to use boundaries between components of a segmented image to create a mesh for finite elements, as described in [Mesh for Images for three materials](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253606/mesh-from-images-for-three-materials/253678) and [meshes with multiple regions from 2D images?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185064/how-to-create-meshes-with-multiple-regions-from-2d-images).

The goal is smooth boundaries that roughly approximate the edges of the segmented components: the exact component boundaries, specified by individual pixels are finer than justified by the blur or noise in the original image.

To create a mesh, the boundaries must not have any gaps. One approach is using the "Contours" property of the components. But these boundaries be very jagged, which leads to unnecessarily fine meshes.

Other approaches are extracting boundaries from ImageMesh of each component, or from a contour plot. Both methods give smoother boundaries, but can have gaps or duplicates.

Is there a way to get boundaries without gaps, as given by the Contours property, but smoother, as given by the ImageMesh or contour plot approaches?

The boundaries should be a form suitable for meshing, e.g., line segments.

**Example**

Create an image:

```
img = Blur[Rasterize[Graphics[{Gray, Rectangle[], Blue, Annulus[]}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> None], RasterSize -> 200], 5]
```

[image: example image for component boundaries]

Segment the image (clustering components is an example, the actual segmentation could come from other methods):

```
components = ClusteringComponents[img, 3];
```

**Method 1: use Cluster property of the segments**

```
boundaries = 
  ComponentMeasurements[components, "Contours", All, 
   "ComponentAssociation"];

Show[Values[
  Graphics[#, PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {0, 200}}, 
     PlotRangePadding -> 10] & /@ boundaries]]
```

[image: boundaries from Contours property]

The boundaries between components are jagged. Also, each such boundary appears twice, once for each of the two neighboring components. Since the two boundaries use exactly the same points, that duplication doesn't cause a problem with meshing.

**Method 2: use ImageMesh boundary of each segment**

```
regions = 
  Table[ImageMesh[
    Image[components /. Thread[DeleteCases[Range[3], i] -> 0]]], {i,3}];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black],Riffle[{Red, LightBlue, Green}, regions]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image: ImageMesh of components]

The boundaries of these regions are smoother than those from the components "Contours" property. But there are slight gaps between the regions, so their boundaries don't quite match, as seen in this detail:

[image: detail of ImageMesh of components]

**Method 3: use a contour plot**

Create a contour plot on a blurred version of the components, with contour values selected to be between the gray levels specified for the components.

```
imgC = ColorConvert[
   Blur[Colorize[components, 
     ColorRules -> {1 -> White, 2 -> Black, 3 -> Gray}], 5], 
   "Grayscale"];

ListContourPlot[Reverse@ImageData@imgC, Contours -> {0.4, 0.8}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Blue, Darker@Green}, BaseStyle -> Thick, 
 ContourShading -> None, 
 Frame -> None, DataRange -> {{0, 200}, {0, 200}},
 (* add outer boundary *)
 Epilog -> Line[{{0, 0}, {200, 0}, {200, 200}, {0, 200}, {0, 0}}]
 ]
```

[image: boundaries from ListContourPlot]

The boundaries are smooth, but with two slightly different boundaries between some of the components.

Comment: Strongly related: [(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11765/280), [(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/223978/280), [(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/166815/280), [(4)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149661/280).

Comment: Also related: [(5)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144342/280), [(6)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17704/280), [(7)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159468/280), [(8)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75855/280).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple approach is to upsize the original image using the `"Lanczos"` resampling method (the default for `ImageResize`) and then apply the [Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202062/280) to remove the jaggies and simplify the curve (see the linked answer for the definition of `dp`):

```
components = ClusteringComponents[ImageResize[img, Scaled[3], Resampling -> "Lanczos"], 3];

boundaries = ComponentMeasurements[components, "Contours", All][[All, 2]];

eps = 1.5;
Graphics[boundaries /. Line[pts_] :> Line[dp[pts, eps]]]
```

> [image: out]

(I've tried playing with other resampling methods, but hadn't found anything better than `"Lanczos"`.)

Alternative method of producing the boundaries using `ListContourPlot` (addition of `InterpolationOrder -> 2` and `Method -> "Spline"` in this case doesn't improve the result):

```
components = ClusteringComponents[img, 3];
lcp = ListContourPlot[Reverse[ArrayPad[components, 2, 1]], Contours -> {1.5, 2.5}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1, ContourStyle -> {Blue, Darker@Green}, BaseStyle -> Thick, 
  ContourShading -> None, Frame -> None, DataRange -> All] // EchoTiming
```

> ```
> 56.9843
> ```

> [image: out]

Applying `GaussianFilter` allows producing smoother boundaries:

```
lcp2 = ListContourPlot[
   GaussianFilter[N@ArrayPad[Reverse[components], 4, 1], 2, Padding -> None], 
   Contours -> {1.5, 2.5}, InterpolationOrder -> 1, ContourStyle -> {Blue, Darker@Green}, 
   BaseStyle -> Thick, ContourShading -> None, Frame -> None, DataRange -> All] // 
  EchoTiming
```

> ```
> 33.9752
> ```

> [image: out]

By adjusting the contour values we can get the boundaries close to each other:

```
lcp2c = ListContourPlot[
   GaussianFilter[N@ArrayPad[Reverse[components], 4, 1], 2, Padding -> None], 
   Contours -> {1.9, 2.1}, InterpolationOrder -> 1, ContourStyle -> {Blue, Darker@Green}, 
   BaseStyle -> Thick, ContourShading -> None, Frame -> None, DataRange -> All] // 
  EchoTiming
```

> ```
> 31.8284
> ```

> [image: out]

Increasing the radius for `GaussianFilter` allows to get even smoother boundaries:

```
lcp2cg = ListContourPlot[
   GaussianFilter[N@ArrayPad[Reverse[components], 6, 1], 3, Padding -> None], 
   Contours -> {1.9, 2.1}, InterpolationOrder -> 2, Method -> "Spline", 
   ContourStyle -> {Blue, Darker@Green}, BaseStyle -> Thick, ContourShading -> None, 
   Frame -> None, DataRange -> All] // EchoTiming
```

> ```
> 118.176
> ```

> [image: out]

Swapping labels `2` and `3` gives other boundaries, what may be useful:

```
components2 = components /. {2 -> 3, 3 -> 2};

lcp3 = ListContourPlot[
   GaussianFilter[N@ArrayPad[Reverse[components2], 6, 1], 4, Padding -> None], 
   Contours -> {1.9, 2.2}, InterpolationOrder -> 2, Method -> "Spline", 
   ContourStyle -> {Blue, Darker@Green}, BaseStyle -> Thick, ContourShading -> None, 
   Frame -> None, DataRange -> All] // EchoTiming
```

> ```
> 306.132
> ```

> [image: out]

The same approach can be applied to the original image data directly, without using `ClusteringComponents`:

```
data = ArrayPad[Map[Total, Reverse@ImageData@img, {2}], 2, 3];
lcp4 = ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> {1.25, 2}, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
   ContourStyle -> {Blue, Darker@Green}, BaseStyle -> Thick, ContourShading -> None, 
   Frame -> None, DataRange -> All] // EchoTiming
```

> ```
> 150.602
> ```

> [image: out]

By adjusting the contour values we can get the boundaries close to each other:

```
data = ArrayPad[Map[# . {4., 4., 0.5} &, Reverse@ImageData@img, {2}], 4, 8.5];
lcp5 = ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> {4, 4.5}, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
   ContourStyle -> {Blue, Darker@Green}, BaseStyle -> Thick, ContourShading -> None, 
   Frame -> None, DataRange -> All] // EchoTiming
```

> ```
> 149.305
> ```

> [image: out]

Comment: Thanks for the variety of useful approaches. Good to have alternatives in case one method doesn't work well for some images. The pointer to the D-P algorithm is especially helpful: simple and effective.

Answer (score 4):

### Update

In the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/) now is available [CurveToBSplineFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CurveToBSplineFunction/). It is a significantly extended and improved version of the function published in the original version of this answer. It can be used as follows:

```
components = ClusteringComponents[img, 3];
(* remove backgound (the component 1)*)
boundaries = ComponentMeasurements[components, "Contours"][[2 ;;, 2]];

(* maximal polynomial degree is 90 *)
functs = ResourceFunction["CurveToBSplineFunction"][#, 90,
      "CurveClosed" -> True][t] & @@@ Flatten[boundaries, 1];
ParametricPlot[functs, {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> False]
```

> [image: output]

Please see additional explanations and examples of use in the [online Documentation](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CurveToBSplineFunction/).

---

### Original answer

Here I present my own implementation of the contour parametrization approach: a function `contourToBSplineFunction`. It can automatically assign weights to the original points based on how far this point is from adjacent points. This approach allows preserving the sharp corners of the original contour. The function also allows specifying the maximal degree of the underlying polynomial basis.

Here is how it can be used:

```
components = ClusteringComponents[img, 3];
(* remove backgound (the component 1)*)
boundaries = ComponentMeasurements[components, "Contours"][[2 ;;, 2]];

(* automatic weghts for the control points (preserve sharp corners), maximal polynomial degree is 90 *)
functs = contourToBSplineFunction[#, 90][t] & @@@ Flatten[boundaries, 1];
ParametricPlot[functs, {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> False]
```

> [image: out]

```
(* equal weghts for the knots, maximal polynomial degree is 90 *)
functs = contourToBSplineFunction[#, 90, False][t] & @@@ Flatten[boundaries, 1];
ParametricPlot[functs, {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> False]
```

> [image: out]

The fourth parameter allows to specify the scale (by default assumed scale `1` corresponding to the distance `1` between adjacent pixels on the plot):

```
functs = contourToBSplineFunction[#, 90, True, 10][t] & @@@ Flatten[boundaries, 1];
ParametricPlot[functs, {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> False]
```

> [image: out]

Parameterizing an arbitrary polygon:

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = RandomPolygon[{"Simple", 30}][[1]];
funct = contourToBSplineFunction[pts, 10, True, .001][t];
ParametricPlot[funct, {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Prolog -> Polygon[pts]]
```

> [image: out]

Definition:

```
ClearAll[contourToBSplineFunction]
contourToBSplineFunction[points_?MatrixQ, maxDegree_Integer : 50, weights_ : True, 
 scale : _?NumberQ : 1] := 
  Block[{pairs, pair2ListW, pairsW},
   pairs = Partition[points, 2, 1, {1, 1}];
   pair2ListW[{{x1_, y1_}, {x1_, y1_}}] = Nothing;
   pair2ListW[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] := 
    Block[{dist = Norm[{x2 - x1, y2 - y1}], n}, n = Floor[dist/scale]; 
     Join[{{{x1, y1}, dist}}, 
      Table[{{x1, y1} + i {x2 - x1, y2 - y1}/n, dist/n}, {i, 1, n - 1}], 
      {{{x2, y2}, dist}}]];
   pairsW = Flatten[pair2ListW /@ pairs, 1];
   BSplineFunction[pairsW[[All, 1]], SplineDegree -> maxDegree, 
    SplineWeights -> If[TrueQ@weights, pairsW[[All, 2]], Automatic], 
    SplineClosed -> True]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a curve parametrization approach based on the [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17780/280) by [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) and its [adaptation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144440/280) by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) for the cases like this. In our case it requires further adaptation because the contours returned by `ComponentMeasurements` aren't suitable "as is" for [Simon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods)'s `tocurve` function.

```
components = ClusteringComponents[ImagePad[img, 4, White], 3];
```

Preliminarily, we must convert our contours to the form suitable for [Simon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods)'s `tocurve` function.

First, we delete consecutive duplicate points (and remove the background component `1`):

```
boundaries = ComponentMeasurements[components, "Contours"][[2 ;;, 2]] //.
   Line[{a___, p_, p_, b___}] :> Line[{a, p, b}];
gr = Graphics[Riffle[{Blue, Darker@Green}, boundaries]]
```

> [image: out]

(It is really strange that `ComponentMeasurements` simplifies the contours in the horizontal and vertical directions, but at the same time creates many consecutive duplicate points...)

Secondly, we fill the vertical and horizontal gaps between successive points in order to make the curves suitable for `Fourier`:

```
boundaries4Fourier = 
  boundaries //. {Line[{a___, {x1_, y1_}, {x1_, y2_}, b___}] /; Abs[y2 - y1] > 1 :> 
     Line[{a, Sequence @@ Table[{x1, y}, {y, y1, y2, Sign[y2 - y1]}], b}], 
    Line[{a___, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y1_}, b___}] /; Abs[x2 - x1] > 1 :> 
     Line[{a, Sequence @@ Table[{x, y1}, {x, x1, x2, Sign[x2 - x1]}], b}]};
```

[Simon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods)'s function:

```
param[x_, m_, t_] := 
  Module[{f, n = Length[x], nf}, 
   f = Chop[Fourier[x]][[;; Ceiling[Length[x]/2]]];
   nf = Length[f];
   Total[(2 Abs[f]/Sqrt[n] Sin[
        Pi/2 - Arg[f] + 2. Pi Range[0, nf - 1] t])[[;; Min[m, nf]]]]];

tocurve[Line[data_], m_, t_] := param[#, m, t] & /@ Transpose[data];
```

[Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)'s code

```
pts = Flatten[boundaries4Fourier, 1][[All, 1]];
divider = 9;(*controls smoothing*)
pp = MapThread[(*parametrized paths*)
  tocurve[Line[#1], #2, t] &, {pts, 
   Max[#, 4] & /@ Round[(Length /@ pts)/divider](*no.of modes-controls smoothing*)}];
pp = pp - (pp /. _Sin -> 0) + (Mean /@ pts);
plot = ParametricPlot[pp, {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> False]
```

> [image: out]

Not ideal, but fast and smooth.